# Custom/OpenSource implementation of EF6 provider model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to understand EF 6 provider model in bit detail. So I was looking at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/providers/provider-model and I read that EF 6 calls DbProviderServices.GetService for registering additional or override existing services offered by EF 6.
So I like to take a detailed view of this process. So my question is: Is there any OpenSource EF 6 Provider functioning code (if it also called Connector, so please do clarify) that is available to see/download/Edit/run

Thank you

Comment: How about the [SqlServer](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/tree/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer) provider from EF6 itself.

Comment: @IvanStoev where is `DbProviderFactory` class in all that. I searched "Find File" and there is nothing exactly matching?

Comment: I think provider factories are coming from the corresponding ADO net provider. The EF6 provider provides just [DbProviderServices](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlProviderServices.cs). Btw, EF6 is considered "obsolete" in regard to EF Core, so investing time in it's internal model doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @IvanStoev how DbProviderServices and DBProviderFactory   are related?